# How do you say "which one of you"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to translate a sentence containing "which one of you" into Japanese, like in "Which one of you took my sandwich?".

Google's search bar was no help - a query for `"which one of you" in Japanese` gave me あなたのその1, which seems to mean "the first of you", and the page results were all for results that simply contained "which one of you" and "Japanese" on the same page.

It seems like it would be something like "あなたたちにどの人" (which person among you), but as I'm not experienced, I don't know if that's the correct form.

I don't want something as general as "誰" (who), because I want to refer to a specific group of people.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, so I might not say things the best way...  but I probably *would* say 誰, trusting context to make it obvious which set of people I was asking about.

Comment: Is dono hito acceptable?

Comment: I'm trying to put emphasis on the "among you" part.

Answer (score 2):

Try to translate meaning, not words. Towards doing this, think of 2 or 3 different ways express what you want to say in English. Match those against your understanding of Japanese grammar. btw: Fight hard not to use second person pronouns. Avoiding them sounds more natural, but also pushes one further away from direct word translations.

Comment: This.  Translating "which one of you" exactly is unnecessary.  "Of you" implies that you're talking directly to the group of "suspects".  So all you really need is "who took my sandwich" (`誰がサンドイッチ盗んだ【ぬすんだ】んだ！`) and it's pretty much implied you're only talking to the suspects.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous answer mentioned, never try to translate directly as far as word choice goes. Always translate the intended meaning instead.

That being said, "Which one of you?" is a question in English that is asking basically "Who" within a group of people. Consider the following phrase:

> あなたたちの中の、(誰/どの人）ですか？
>   Within (all of) you, who is it?

That being said, this is a phrase you'd be using to select one specific person out of a specific group of people.